# I have purchase one item and need to distribute amount to two different merchant or sellar in one transaction using paypal node js

Tags: ios, node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

**note:**- I have already payment done with parallel payment but it depreciates any other way to implement?